# svn merge trunk branch vs. svn merge trunk

Tags: svn, merge

I'm having my local copy of a branch and want to merge from trunk, but found something rather odd.

What's the difference between

svn merge ^/trunk

and

svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/my_branch

I thought they were the same but the first is not merging all the code and the second one is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Merge has 3 forms with three distinct behaviors.

The first form you used in your question is a sync merge, it implies -r 1:REV and will merge all eligible changes to a branch from its immediate ancestor branch.

The second form is a "2-URL Merge" and the difference between ^/trunk ^/branches/my_branch generated and applied to your working copy.

The three forms are described in the "Version Control with Subversion" book. ( http://svnbook.red-bean.com )

Comment: So it means that in the 2nd form I don't have to make a commit, it's automatically done.

Comment: I guess something is wrong because I did the following: svn co  /branches/my_branch  ./branch1   then svn co  /branches/my_branch  ./branch2 then cd branch2 then svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/my_branch then go to branch1 and svn update, I'd expect that branch1 would get the code merged. But is not. Also make the svn diff and the chenges merged don't reflect in neither of local branches.

Comment: Also getting back to the question. If I do a svn co /branches/my_branch ./branch then cd branch then svn merge ^/trunk and lastly svn commit -m "merge from trunk". If I do the svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/my_branch it still merge some changes.

Comment: The merge commands just make changes to your working copy.  You then should review, make any adjustments if necessary, and commit.  That commit is a separate operation.  Sounds like you weren't expecting this and that's causing confusion.